# Exception when creating Swap Chain with CreateSwapChainForComposition

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, sharpdx, directx-12

I am trying to render **DirectX12** in **SwapChainPanel** by using **SharpDx** but creating a SwapChain fails for an unknown reason. Here is a simplified version of what I have:

```
// select adapter based on some simple scoring mechanism
SelectedAdapter = SelectAdapter();

// create device
using (var defaultDevice = new Device(SelectedAdapter, FeatureLevel.Level_12_0))
    Device = defaultDevice.QueryInterface<SharpDX.Direct3D12.Device2>();

// describe swap chain
SwapChainDescription1 swapChainDescription = new SwapChainDescription1
{
    AlphaMode = AlphaMode.Ignore,
    BufferCount = 2,
    Format = Format.R8G8B8A8_UNorm,
    Height = (int)(MainSwapChainPanel.RenderSize.Height),
    Width = (int)(MainSwapChainPanel.RenderSize.Width),
    SampleDescription = new SampleDescription(1, 0),
    Scaling = Scaling.Stretch,
    Stereo = false,
    SwapEffect = SwapEffect.FlipSequential,
    Usage = Usage.RenderTargetOutput
};

// create swap chain
using (var factory2 = SelectedAdapter.GetParent<Factory2>())
{
    /*--> throws exception:*/
    SwapChain1 swapChain1 = new SwapChain1(factory2, Device, ref swapChainDescription);
    SwapChain = swapChain1.QueryInterface<SwapChain2>();
}

// tie created swap chain with swap chain panel
using (ISwapChainPanelNative nativeObject = ComObject.As<ISwapChainPanelNative>(MainSwapChainPanel))
    nativeObject.SwapChain = SwapChain;
```

Selection of adapter works as expected (I have 2 adapters + software adapter). I can create a device and I can see that the app in task manager is using that selected adapter.

Creation of the swap chain is based mostly on this documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/gaming/directx-and-xaml-interop#swapchainpanel-and-gaming

I get *factory2* (with all the adapters and other things enumerated). Constructor of *SwapChain1* internally is using *factory2* to create a swap chain: https://github.com/sharpdx/SharpDX/blob/master/Source/SharpDX.DXGI/SwapChain1.cs#L64

I compared this method with several others examples and tutorials and this is the way it should be done, however, regardless of the *Format* I choose or adapter, I keep getting this exception:

> {SharpDX.SharpDXException: HRESULT: [0x887A0001], Module:
>   [SharpDX.DXGI], ApiCode: [DXGI_ERROR_INVALID_CALL/InvalidCall],
>   Message: The application made a call that is invalid. Either the
>   parameters of the call or the state of some object was incorrect.
>   Enable the D3D debug layer in order to see details via debug messages.
>
> at SharpDX.Result.CheckError()    at
>   SharpDX.DXGI.Factory2.CreateSwapChainForComposition(IUnknown
>   deviceRef, SwapChainDescription1& descRef, Output restrictToOutputRef,
>   SwapChain1 swapChainOut)    at SharpDX.DXGI.SwapChain1..ctor(Factory2
>   factory, ComObject device, SwapChainDescription1& description, Output
>   restrictToOutput)    at UI.MainPage.CreateSwapChain()}

*DebugLayer* doesn't show any additional info.

The app itself is a regular Windows Universal Blank App (min target version Creators Update 15063). I know I can run Directx12 on my current hardware (C++ hello world works just fine).

Any ideas what is wrong?

Comment: Last time I had issues creating a SwapChain I had to create a new DeviceContext first.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I got it working:

```
try
{
    using (var factory4 = new Factory4())
    {
        SwapChain1 swapChain1 = new SwapChain1(factory4, CommandQueue, ref swapChainDescription);
        SwapChain = swapChain1.QueryInterface<SwapChain2>();
    }
 }
 catch (Exception e)
 {
     Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
     return;
 }

 using (ISwapChainPanelNative nativeObject = ComObject.As<ISwapChainPanelNative>(MainSwapChainPanel))
     nativeObject.SwapChain = SwapChain;
```

So basically I need Factory4 interface to create temporary SwapChain1 from which I can query SwapChain2, then this SwapChain2 can be attached to SwapChainPanel.

Also, a very important thing to notice here is that even though SwapChain1 constructor signature (and documentation) https://github.com/sharpdx/SharpDX/blob/master/Source/SharpDX.DXGI/SwapChain1.cs#L51 says that 2nd argument should be device - it shouldn't. What you need to pass is a CommandQueue object. I have no idea why.

Also, constructor of SwapChain1 says it needs Factory2, but no, you have to pass Factory4!

Comment: CommandQueues replace devices in direct12 so that part makes sense